meaning of the phraze "do <<something>> on <<someone>>"
I read this phrase "no dying on me now" and want to know what it means.
Especially I am interested in the meaning of "do something on someone". Please if possible could you provide some examples but not only the definition.

Daying? Really? Where?

@MichaelHarvey ) thanks.

Related question. To die on me means 'die while you are with me/under my care'.

@Kate Bunting THanks!

In general, to insert verb on someone, e.g. don't die on me, I won't quit on you, etc, means to let a person down or inconvenience them in some way, but we may say 'don't die on me!' to a sick or injured person as a kind of joke, to encourage them.

The phrase die on is similar to cheat on, which means “be unfaithful to,” as in marital infidelity. For both phrases, the object (complement) of on is the victim of the transgression. Another example is tell on, meaning “inform [some authority] about misdeeds of.” Likewise, an employer who is relying on an employee and fears that the employee may leave might say, “Don’t quit on me.” In each of these, the action is being considered from the perspective of the victim, as it were—even in the ironic case of die on.

It can also be used when the action is not being performed by a person. "The basement might flood on me if I don't repair the leak." "It would be a shame if it rained on us this Sunday at the parade." This could be understood as literally "the rain would fall down and land on us" but the more readily understood meaning is "it would be unfortunate" or "It would inconvenience us."

The phrase die on is similar to cheat on, which means “be unfaithful to,” as in marital infidelity. For both phrases, the object (complement) of on is the victim of a wrong (in the former case, the wrong is that of being made to mourn or (at least when it’s used ironically) being inconvenienced).
Another example is tell on, meaning “inform [some authority] about misdeeds of,” as one child might do to another. Criminals used to speak of police informants as ratting on others.  Likewise, an employer who is relying on an employee and fears that the employee may leave might say, “Don’t quit on me.”
Each of these constructions of the form V on, emphasizes not so much the action taken as its effects on the other party, even in the ironic case of die on.
